# Event Tracking not working in Universal Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, universal-analytics

Last Friday I upgraded our sites to use the Google Universal Analytics analytics.js code. Pageviews are tracking just fine, but my event tracking is not working — our events crashed to 0 over the weekend, and nothing I've tried shows up in the Real-Time view.

I've read the documentation on the Google Analytics developer site (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events), and I've reviewed the advice given here on a number of similar questions. I believe I've set this up correctly, but I can't seem to see any of the event hits.

I track all our links through some jQuery that attaches an event handler to all the links on the page. Here's how it used to record the links before upgrading to Universal Analytics (linkAction and eventLabel are strings, eventTime is an int):

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Links', linkAction, eventLabel, eventTime]);
```

Since upgrading, I've tried it two different ways:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Links', linkAction, eventLabel, eventTime);
```

and:

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Links',
  eventAction: linkAction,
  eventLabel: eventLabel,
  eventValue: eventTime
});
```

Using the GA Debug plugin for Chrome, I see that the event handlers are executing, producing the following outputs respectively:

```
Running command: ga("send", "event", "Links", "Internal", "News and Events")
```

and:

```
Running command: ga("send", {hitType: "event", eventCategory: "Links", 
eventAction: "Internal", eventLabel: "Preeminent Teams", eventValue: 17})
```

Yet those clicks don't show up in the Real-Time analytics view.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but for the life of me I can't see what it is.

Comment: Do you have any filters set up that would block your visits (and hence your events)? You may be seeing them in GA Debugger, but filters may prevent you from seeing them in Real Time.

Comment: Can you look in the network panel of developers tools and verify that the actual 'collect' request to google-analytics.com is being sent for the event and not being cancelled for some reason.  The GA debugger shows commands the JS is processing but that doesnt necessarily mean the HTTP request is completing.  If it is completing can you paste the complete URL that is used

Comment: Mystery solved, and the answer is a big "Duh-OH!"

Comment: Our sites record pageviews to both the College of Engineering's account, and the Purdue University account. It turns out I got the account numbers reversed, so that the default account was Purdue's, instead of Engineering's. 

I finally figured it out when I noticed that events were still being recorded for sites that use our old template, but not for the ones using the latest one. That led me to compare the basic analytics code that sets up the trackers, and then I realized that I'd gotten the account numbers switched in the latest version.

Comment: Excellent, well done.  We've all done similar things before!  Brings me back to my suggestion though - always check the raw HTTP requests to google-analytics when seeing issues with data or missing data.